# what is the difference between jtype (of JNI) and type of C/C++?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, native

In JNI there are jtypes. Like `jint` for `int` and `jboolean` for `boolean`. I understand the latter types are c/c++ types . But type is a `jtype` ? In books they mention this type also a *native* type. What is meant by that ?

***EDIT:***

What is the use of jtype ?

Comment: It's probably just a typedef for the corresponding type. Like `typedef std::int32_t jint`.

Comment: There is no 'jtype' in jni.h Maybe it's a shortcut to 'Jni TYPEs'

Comment: @Jerome by jtype i mean _jchar , jint , jshort , jlong , jbyte , jdouble_.....

Comment: Oh, I thought you actually found jint, jlong...etc and jtype. Then I believe, like Pubby wrote, that they all are typedefs (typedef long jint). Probably because some types (long for example is a __int64 on W32 x86 JDK6) are machine-dependant therefore you can't really rely on the non-jtypes primitive. Not sure though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`jni.h`](http://xdprof.sourceforge.net/doxygen/jni_8h.html),

```
typedef unsigned char   jboolean
typedef unsigned short  jchar
typedef short   jshort
typedef float   jfloat
typedef double  jdouble
typedef long    jint
typedef jint    jsize
```

By native types they don't mean native to Java language, they mean native C or native machine equivalents. The `j` versions, aid to  [map Java types to native C types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html). ***The advantage of this mapping is, a Java programmer familiar with basic Java types can continue using the same names with the just the added `j`. He need not bother how are they mapped into the machine's basic type. It will be taken care by the typedefs. Also if the underlying machine architecture changes, still you need not bother, just chaging the typedefs will do***

Addressing your concerns in comments, `_jstring` is a class. And `jstring` is a pointer to this class

```
class _jstring : public _jobject {};
typedef _jstring *jstring;
```

Just like we have the `String` class in C++

Comment: then what exactly is the use of _jtype_ ? If it is just the typedef

Comment: you can get all the type def from  jdk/include/jni.h

Comment: It helps you to convert from c-inner-type to java-inner-type. You can do it yourself. javah and jni.h makes it easier